# How to combine two .net mvc projects

Tags: asp.net, .net

I downloaded and successfully ran 2 quick start projects from azure: AAD B2C and Document DB. They both are mvc projects with their .sln file, web.config file etc... I would like now to merge/ combine them into one single solution, so I can publish them to the same WebApp in Azure. What is the recommended approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC V2 has a feature called Areas which allows you to have separate projects referenced by the main application.

**[`Merge two MVC projects - scott`](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released)**

Comment: Thanks, then should I import all files manually? What about global.asax, web.config, packages?